# TryParseExact - Finding Date in the Middle of a Line of Text

Tags: c#, date, tryparse

Good morning and happy end of the world to you all, I have a date related issue which is non apocalyptic related

I'm trying locate a date within a text document. The line with the date on it has text in front and behind it however when I use the **TryParseExact** I only seem to be able to find the date if its at the beginning of the line of text.

How would I go about altering the below code to search for a date which is located around 20 characters in on the line of text?

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
            var format1 = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            var fileDates1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(z)
                            .Where(l => l.Length >= format1.Length
                                        && DateTime.TryParseExact(l.Substring(0, format1.Length)
```

Comment: What is the pattern ? How would you know about the position of the Date in the line ? also could you post sample lines containing the date,

Comment: The date is coming from some reports I have, here is the sample line you have requested: <item name="assettag" source="user">BW 17/11/1981</item>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is indeed checking only at the beginning of the line.

You can combine a regular expression to find things that *look* like dates, and then proper parsing to check that the "date" is valid:

```
DateTime d;
var format1 = "dd/MM/yyyy";
Regex r = new Regex("[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9]{4}");
var linesWithDates = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(z)
    .Where(l => r.Matches(l).Cast<Match>()
         .Any(DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value, format1, ...)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to find your date in text;

```
String text = File.ReadAllLines(z);
String pattern = @"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}";
String dateString = Regex.Match(text, pattern).Value;
```